# I can send GET requests to a local Laravel API, but all POST requests fail

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, post

I've got a basic Laravel API that I'm trying to set up. I've set up a CORS middleware, and I'm making requests to the API from a different (local) domain (i.e., `aaa.host` is a React front-end making Axios requests to a `bbb.host` Laravel API back-end).

All GET requests successfully go through the API and return a response, but any POST requests I attempt fail. My understanding is that the CSRF token is only required in Laravel for web requests, not API requests. As such, I can't understand what I'm missing and why POST requests aren't going through. If I change a POST route to a GET route, it instantly works, so the fact that it's a POST route seems to be the issue.

Here's an example of what the failed POST request looks like in the Chrome console:

[image]

I've looked at the Laravel API docs, but I don't understand what I'm missing. Does anyone have any ideas? Also, for what it's worth, I'm using Laravel 5.8.29. Thank you.

---

**Edit**: Here's what `routes/api.php` looks like:

```
Route::middleware(['cors'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('/missing-subpath-on-purpose/item/create', 'SomeController@createItem');
});
```

Again, if I change `Route::post` to `Route::get` and make an Axios GET request instead of a POST, it works fine.

Comment: Are the routes declared in routes/api.php?

Comment: Yes, please see my edit above. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, what response do you get from Postman?

Comment: Okay. Very weird. A request from Postman goes through fine and works, but requests from Axios from my other local domain fails. I should have checked that before. Sorry. Any ideas?

Comment: I presume an OPTIONS request is also needed for preflight requests on your route?

Comment: @nice_dev, could you please explain what that means? I don't understand. I have to make an OPTIONS request first to make a POST request when doing it from Axios on another domain front-end? Why?

Comment: Well, since it's cross domain, the browser would send a preflight request to check if you are authorised to access it. Does `Route::match(['OPTIONS','POST'])`  help? You will have to handle options request in your CORS middleware itself.

Comment: @nice_dev, you hit the nail on the head. Thank you. It took some testing to verify, but the browser was stopping the request going through because the Content-Type was `application/json`. That's a browser thing, which is why Postman was working. I changed the default Content-Type for Axios requests to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Content-type usually shouldn't be an issue for the response to go through. But never mind, you got it fixed and working ;)

Comment: I wouldn't think so either, but I can unequivocally say that `application/json` posts from the browser failed, but changing the Content-Type worked. Maybe there's something in the Laravel API layers that's doing that, I don't know. But then again, the Postman requests worked with `application/json`, so who knows. I think it's a browser thing, not a Content-Type thing.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to nice_dev for identifying the real problem and helping me solve it. Turns out that the Laravel API was fine and sending POST requests to it from Postman worked fine.

The issue was with the browser itself. If you send a POST request with a Content-Type of `application/json`, the browser will force two requests to occur, which was causing all sorts of problems. (I don't know at the moment the reasons for this, but I'm sure browser-makers have their reasons for doing things this way.)

Nevertheless, by changing the default Content-Type for all Axios requests in the browser to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it solved my problem. Thank you.

---

**Edit**: After playing around with this more, I realized that I did want to be making `application/json` requests, but doing so was causing the aforementioned issues with CORS.

To fix this, I created the following CORS middleware in Laravel:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class Cors {
        public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

I then added it to the global middleware in `Kernel.php` as follows:

```
protected $middleware = [
    ..., // Other middleware here.
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

The mistake I had made is that the CORS middleware wasn't part of the global middleware, but the route middleware, which was causing the issues.